# In which of Tolkien's works does the Witch-King of Angmar appear?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit, tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

Where can I read all about the Witch-King of Angmar? Does he appear anywhere other than the Lord of the Rings trilogy and its appendices?

The appendices talk about the Angmar vs Arnor war very vaguely and without detail. In online wikis there is tons of information about this war, and if I recall correctly it lasted over 400 years. Where can I find the source of this information, assuming that the  extreme detail in the wiki was not simply made up. *LOTR* itself? *The Hobbit* (unlikely)? *History of Middle Earth*? *The Unfinished Tales*? *The Silmarillion?* Does anyone know?

Comment: Though I'm upvoting @ianthompson's answer, I'm curious which wiki in particular you're thinking of. That might help answer the question of where the details came from.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He gets a few mentions in 'Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age' (The Silmarillion), but I don't think there is much that isn't covered in the appendices to the Lord of the Rings. He also features prominently in 'The Hunt for the Ring' (Unfinished Tales), though unfortunately there are several versions of this story and it's not clear which should be considered canon.